# Trying to draw a polygon on the MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

Codes as the below pic shows:

[image: Polygon]

I was trying to create a simple polygon on my `MapView` to mark a specific area.

I have already set up the coordinates,counts also the polygonview.

what else did I miss?

why didn't the mapview showed anything?

Comment: you need to return `polygon` instead if mapView

Comment: Always paste your code instead of Screenshot.

Comment: @PiyushRathi, it didn't work out.

Comment: @Mahesh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing swift vs ObjC, but it appears you're dealing with the MapKit delegate function looking for a polygon renderer, based on the method you're showing and the error message.

MapKit passes you the overlay that it wants to render, you determine the type of that overlay (a polygon in this case), then create and configure a renderer instance that it can use to display the polygon and return that object.  The same call is used by MapKit to get renderers for poly lines and tile overlay images, so you need to check the type if you will have any other overlays.

In swift the definition of the renderer for that would look like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
{
    switch overlay
    {
    case is MKPolygon:
        let polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)

        polygonRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.white

        return polygonRenderer

    default:
        [whatever for poly lines, map overlays, etc.]
    }
}
```

where you're providing mapView with the renderer to display your polygon.  Given that we're accessing the same API, I'd assume you need to do something similar.

Wrong language, but I hope it helps...